# Using a block markup tag strips out elements of block created in pagebuilder

Tags: magento2, blocks, cms, page-builder

When I create a block with pagebuilder that includes background images for the rows, image elements and buttons they all get stripped out when using the `{{block id=''}}` tag on another page

There is nothing listed on the [docs](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/marketing/markup-tags.html) about preventing the stripping? is there another method i could include the block on a page without the elements being removed?

This is a screenshot of my block which should have a nice background image:

[image]

Comment: I am guessing you want to add content block in a page built using page builder. In this case you do not have to add content through the markup instead you can do it through GUI as suggested in the dev document https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/cms/page-builder-add-content-block.html

Comment: @VivekKumar this has been tested and works. if you create an answer i'll accept

Comment: sure thing Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you want to add content block in a page built using page builder. In this case you do not have to add content through the markup instead you can do it through GUI as suggested in Magento developer documentation [here](https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/cms/page-builder-add-content-block.html)